# What is the proper way of referencing css and js files with handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

I am currently using express and handlebars for my project. It is my first time of using handlebars and I cannot figure out how to properly reference the position of my css and js files

My current project structure is like below

```
- test (root)
  -views
    -js
      -some JS files
    -css
      -some css files
    -layout
      -main.handlebars
  - servers.js (my server)
```

so I did following in my main.handlebars layout file

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    {{#each css}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/{{this}}">
    {{/each}}
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
    {{#each js}}
        <script src="../js/{{this}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```

And inside `{{this}}`, index.css goes in for css and index.js goes in for js.

But this gave `Cannot GET 404 http://localhost:8000/js/index.js` error. So I thought maybe handlebars look from the root somehow. so I tried

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    {{#each css}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/{{this}}">
    {{/each}}
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
    {{#each js}}
        <script src="views/js/{{this}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```

But this gave `Cannot GET 404 http://localhost:8000/views/js/index.js` error when it looks to be the correct position of the file.

What is the correct way of referencing the js and css file in handlebars?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should create the public directory and in the server, you can serve static files such as `images`, `fonts`, `CSS` files, and **JavaScript** files, use the `express.static` built-in middleware function in Express.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

[image]

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    {{#each css}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{this}}">
    {{/each}}
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
    {{#each js}}
        <script src="/js/{{this}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```